# NSData getting trucated while converting from Pdf

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, nsdata

I am trying to upload a pdf from iClouds in iPhone in Objective C. The following is my code which gets triggered on click.

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *doc = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc]initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.composite-content"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
doc.delegate = (id)self;
doc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentViewController:doc animated:YES completion:nil];//getting the path of the file selected through  didPickDocumentAtURL
NSString *path = [url path];//converting in to data in two different ways but getting truncated nsdata
NSData *data3 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];//Truncating
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];//Truncating Both data3 and data1 are getting truncated after 32767 characters.
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this correct format for importing a .pdf into `NSData`?
2. Is there any limit for `NSData`? (I am asking this because it's getting truncated exactly after 32767 characters)

Comment: What is the actual issue/result? And what do you expect?

Comment: why don't you use `CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL`?

Comment: To upload a pdf to server I need to convert the pdf to base64 string
So I am converting the file to data and data to base64String using  [data3 base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];

Comment: @PiyushPatel I am New to iOs family I haven't used CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL till now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by calling the delegate method of UIDocumentPickerViewController

```
  - (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url{
                if (controller.documentPickerMode== UIDocumentPickerModeImport) {
                      //taking the path of the file selected
                       NSString *path = [url path];
                      //converting to NSData
                        NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];
                       //converting to base64 string
                        base64String = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];

                 }
     }
```